# Java Tic tac toe AI element not working

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

So, trying to make a 'simple' tic-tac-toe app that matches user input with an 'AI' that picks (just at random), empty cells to enter as an entity to play against.
The problem I am having is that the true/false switch that I am using (in `playerClick`) to decide whos turn it is, does not seem to be working. It remains true throughout.
This means and (I believe is the cause of), my AI's method, `aiPlayerPick` which is tied to `randomButtonPick`, is not being run, only the input from the human user is ever entered.
My question then, is where is my logic falling apart here?

I think that's clear enough without babbling on too much.
Any clarification needed, please just ask.

Thanks.

```
package com.example.richardcurteis.connect3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean noughtsTurn;
    ArrayList board;
    Players player;
    String aiPickedButton;

    public void receiveClick(View view) {
        String buttonPressed = String.valueOf(view.getTag());
        board.remove(buttonPressed);
        System.out.println(board);
        System.out.println("receiveClick: " + noughtsTurn); // Is noughtsTurn true or false?
        humanPlayerTurn(view);
        aiPlayerTurn(view);

    }

    public void humanPlayerTurn(View view) {
        playerClick(view);
        noughtsTurn = false; // Set noughtsTurn to false for next player to have their turn
    }
   public void aiPlayerTurn(View view) {
       aiPickedButton = randomButtonPick();
       playerClick(view);
       noughtsTurn = true; // Set noughtsTurn to true for first player to start again
   }

    public void playerClick(View view) {
        Button B;
        if (view instanceof Button) {
            B = (Button) view;
            if ( noughtsTurn ) {
                B.setText(player.noughtsPlayer());
                B.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                aiPlayerPick(); // This is where the AI process should mirror human input
            }
        }
    }

    public String randomButtonPick() {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        String arrayItem = (String) board.get(randomNumber.nextInt(board.size()));
        return arrayItem;
    }

    public Button aiPlayerPick() {
        Button btn = null;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button && view.getTag() == aiPickedButton) {

                        View btn_v = view.findViewWithTag(aiPickedButton);
                        btn = (Button) btn_v;
                        btn.setText(player.crossesPlayer());
                        btn.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return btn;
    }

    public class Players {
        public String noughtsPlayer() { return "O"; }
        public String crossesPlayer() { return "X"; }
        //public String blankButton() { return ""; } // Will be implemented eventually to help clear board
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        boolean noughtsTurn = true;
        System.out.println("Start: " + noughtsTurn);
        board = new ArrayList();
        for (int x = 0; x < getBoardSize(); x++) {
            String y = String.valueOf(x);
            board.add(y);
        }
        player = new Players();

    }

    public int getBoardSize() {
        int buttonCount = 0;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button) {
                        buttonCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return buttonCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="#070000">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton1"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="0" />
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton2"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton3"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton5"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton6"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="5"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton7"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton8"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton9"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="8" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button

        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logs and errors:

```
01-04 23:08:58.520 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-04 23:08:58.627 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3-1/lib/x86
01-04 23:08:58.977 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: Start: true
01-04 23:08:59.008 4380-4407/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-04 23:08:59.138 4380-4407/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 23:08:59.192 4380-4407/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 23:08:59.192 4380-4407/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabe05620, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-04 23:09:06.653 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:06.654 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: false
01-04 23:09:09.088 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:09.088 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:11.709 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:11.709 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:15.156 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:15.156 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:16.418 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:16.418 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:17.060 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [3, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:17.061 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:17.664 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [6, 7, 8]
01-04 23:09:17.672 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:18.378 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [7, 8]
01-04 23:09:18.378 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:18.905 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [8]
01-04 23:09:18.913 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:19.487 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: []
01-04 23:09:19.489 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: receiveClick: true
01-04 23:09:19.494 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 23:09:19.494 4380-4380/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.richardcurteis.connect3, PID: 4380
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
       at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
       at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.randomButtonPick(MainActivity.java:60)
       at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.aiPlayerTurn(MainActivity.java:40)
       at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.receiveClick(MainActivity.java:31)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: most important part: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
       at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)` it implicates that board.size() == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True/False issue fixed.
Problem was this line in `onCreate()`:

`boolean noughtsTurn = true;`

The boolean, `noughtsTurn` was also declared at the top of the page as such.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean noughtsTurn;
    ArrayList board;
    Players player;
    String aiPickedButton;
    ...
    ...
```

This meant that it was always true.
Changed to the below in `onCreate` and now the true/false switch works fine.

`noughtsTurn = true;`